# gitlab kubernets runner failing to authenticate in private docker registry during prepare stage

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-registry

Im setting up a gitlab runner in my kubernets cluster.
The runner is properly deployed and running. When I trigger any pipeline, during the prepare stage it fails with an authentication error to pull from my private docker registry:

```
Preparing the "kubernetes" executor 00:00
Using Kubernetes namespace: gitlab-runner
Using Kubernetes executor with image myprivaterepo.com/terraform:light ...
Using attach strategy to execute scripts...
Preparing environment 00:04
Waiting for pod gitlab-runner/runner-d8cjrcgf-project-2156-concurrent-0nhsjb to be running, status is Pending
    ContainersNotInitialized: "containers with incomplete status: [init-permissions]"
    ContainersNotReady: "containers with unready status: [build helper]"
    ContainersNotReady: "containers with unready status: [build helper]"
WARNING: Failed to pull image with policy "": image pull failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "myprivaterepo.com/terraform:light": failed to resolve reference "myprivaterepo.com/terraform:light": pulling from host myprivaterepo.com failed with status code [manifests light]: 401 Unauthorized
ERROR: Job failed: prepare environment: waiting for pod running: pulling image "myprivaterepo.com/terraform:light": image pull failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "myprivaterepo.com/terraform:light": failed to resolve reference "myprivaterepo.com/terraform:light": pulling from host myprivaterepo.com failed with status code [manifests light]: 401 Unauthorized. Check https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/shells/index.html#shell-profile-loading for more information
```

I already tried by adding in the runner deployment imagePullSecrets (kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson) and also in the gitlab -> Settings -> CI/CD -> environment variable -> DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG but no success for any of those.

Where is the correct place to add it? Im using helm chart.

my .gitlab-ci.yaml:

```
  .base-terraform:
    image:
      name: myprivaterepo.com/terraform:light
```

Answer (score 0):

In my DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG I had a domain with different port than the actual one. gilab-ci used this project env variable automatically as it should be.